# MechanicalSoup StatefulBrowser: Unable to Open URL

Tags: python, mechanicalsoup

I have a Python script using MechanicalSoup StatefulBrowser to open URL that used to work. But it stopped working recently opening a specific website, and I haven't changed any code.

I tried opening other websites, and it's fine.  This is the specific website that fails to open: http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ComplaintsByAddressServlet?allbin=4606689

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

# open url test
url = "http://www.cnn.com"
print("opening website: {}".format(url))
browser.open(url)
print("done website: {}".format(url))

url = "http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ComplaintsByAddressServlet?allbin=4606689"
print("opening website: {}".format(url))
browser.open(url)
print("done website: {}".format(url))
```

The following is the output I got is from www.cnn.com which opened up as expected. But the 2nd link just hangs.

Any help?  Or if anyone know of a way to contact MechanicalSoup developer, please let me know.

Output:

```
opening website: http://www.cnn.com
done website: http://www.cnn.com
opening website: http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ComplaintsByAddressServlet?allbin=4606689
... hangs ...
```

Thank you.

Comment: this code works for me. Maybe you are on their blacklist and they block you. Can you connect with web browser?

Comment: I run code second time and now it doesn't works. It seem now they block me too :)

Comment: I can connect again if I use `browser.set_user_agent('Mozilla/5.0')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many portals block connection if it has wrong header "User-Agent" which inform server what web browser is used to connect.

Python's tools (like `requests`) often use word `Python` in `User-Agent` so server can recognize that it is not real web browser and block connection.

If I use text `"Mozilla/5.0"` as `User-Agent` then I can connect again

```
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.set_user_agent('Mozilla/5.0')
```

Text `"Mozilla/5.0"` is not full text used by read web browser so you could find better text. Or it should be python's module with User-Agent from different web browsers so you can use different values in different days.

Comment: Note that a website blocking a connection based on the user-agent probably doesn't want a bot to crawl its content, so while technically correct, using `set_user_agent` is usually against the will, and most likely against the general sales conditions of the website (i.e. illegal).

Comment: Thanks, this works. Understood on the point on the will of the website. Let me review their policy again. This used to be fine, they might have modified their policy.